# Get the updated cookie value in PHP in a bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I have a bootstrap modal in my php file and the modal consist with Yes and Cancel buttons and a question text and upon clicking the yes button i'm updating the value of my cookie using `setCookie` method.  I need to change the text inside the modal according to the updated cookie value. I have used a if condition to change the text according to the cookie value. But the issue is even though the cookie value is changed, the updated value cannot be retrieved to the modal. It just shows the initial value but does not update when the cookie value is changed.

To get the COOKIE value for the modal i'm using this `$_COOKIE['total_bookings']`.

My code for the modal is as follows

```
<i class="fa fa-trash" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#removeBookingModalCenter" onclick="setRemoveBookingId(<?php echo $room->ID;?>,[<?php echo $i; ?>]);" style="color:#D2335B;cursor:pointer"></i>
<!-- Remove Booking Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="removeBookingModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="socialLoginModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
         <h5 class="modal-title" id="socialLoginModalLongTitle">Remove booking</h5>
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
         <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
         </button>
      </div>
      <?php $totalBookings = ((int)$_COOKIE['total_bookings']) ?>
      <?php if ($totalBookings !== 1) { ?>
      <div class="modal-body mundana-login-wrapper">
         <label>Are you sure you want to remove this booking?</label>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" onclick="removeBooking();" id="remove_booking" class="mundana-button primary ghost" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
         <button type="button" onclick="cancelRemoveBooking();" class="mundana-button ghost" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
      </div>
      <?php } else { ?>
      <div class="modal-body mundana-login-wrapper">
         <label>You are about to remove the only selected room. Do you want to remove?</label>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" onclick="removeBooking();" id="remove_booking" class="mundana-button primary ghost" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
         <button type="button" onclick="cancelRemoveBooking();" class="mundana-button ghost" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
   </div>
</div>
```

To be more clear this is the part where i'm using the if condition. It is here the issue comes where i cannot get the updated cookie value.

```
<?php $totalBookings = ((int)$_COOKIE['total_bookings']) ?>
<?php if ($totalBookings !== 1) { ?>
      <div class="modal-body mundana-login-wrapper">
         <label>Are you sure you want to remove this booking?</label>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" onclick="removeBooking();" id="remove_booking" class="mundana-button primary ghost" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
         <button type="button" onclick="cancelRemoveBooking();" class="mundana-button ghost" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
      </div>
      <?php } else { ?>
      <div class="modal-body mundana-login-wrapper">
         <label>You are about to remove the only selected room. Do you want to remove?</label>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" onclick="removeBooking();" id="remove_booking" class="mundana-button primary ghost" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
         <button type="button" onclick="cancelRemoveBooking();" class="mundana-button ghost" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
```

UPDATE:

Here my code for setting the cookie

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  let expires = "expires=" + d.toISOString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function removeBooking() {
   setCookie("total_bookings", number_of_rooms - 1, 1);
}
```

Comment: removeBooking function is written in a js file. In there i've used the setCookie function. I have inspected if the cookie is getting updated and it's updated successfully. The problem is getting that value to the popup.

Comment: Show us the code, instead of giving us vague descriptions! _“But the issue is even though the cookie value is changed, the updated value cannot be retrieved to the modal.”_ - so where/how did you _try_ to update your modal then? Are you trying to update it using only JavaScript? Or do you want to re-render it on the server side? In the latter case, you would either need to reload the whole page then, or make an AJAX request in the background.

Comment: @CBroe i have updated my question with the code to set the cookie